# ReSharper Formatting Ternary Operator in C#

Tags: c#, resharper

This is driving me up the wall now.  The ternary formatting options in ReSharper -> Options -> C# do not cover indentation, just spacing of '?' and ':' characters, and line chopping.

What I want is:

```
var x = expr1
      ? expr2
      : expr3;
```

But what I get is:

```
var x = expr1
? expr2
: expr3;
```

If the ternary operator formatting was offering no assistance, I thought that the *Chained binary expressions* may help, but no.  That is set as follows.

```
var a = someOperand + operand2
        + operand3
        + operand4;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you changed any of the other formatting options either in ReSharper or Visual Studio itself? Using your first code sample, when I paste it into a C# file I get the indentation as you have written and when I write the expression on one line and put newlines in manually after the '?' and ':' tokens, the indentation appears as expected when I type ';'

Comment: This behaviour only started when I installed resharper 9.  What version are you on?

Comment: I'm using ReSharper 8.2.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try enabling `ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Other | Align Multiline Constructs | Expression`